# Снова оборот с "такие, как"

Tags: пунктуация

Опять вопрос на сравнительный оборот. Если после перечисления предложение продолжается, то надо ли закрывать оборот?

Такие требовательные заказчики, как... перечисление...и многие другие (,) доверяют качеству наших изделий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...надо ли закрывать оборот?

НАДО.

Comment: Т.е. "и многие другие", "и т. п." входят в оборот, и после перечисления всех однородных членов такие обороты всегда закрываются? Спасибо.